# Does it exist an inverse operation for the vertical lift of a vector field on $M$ to $TM$?

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry

Let $M$ be a differentiable manifold and $TM$ its tangent bundle. Let $X$ be a vector field on $M$, locally given by
$$ X=X^i \frac{\partial  } {\partial q^i}.$$
Then its vertical lift is the vector field on $TM$ given by
$$X^v= X^i \frac{\partial  } {\partial \dot{q}^i},$$
where $q$ are the coordinates on $U\subset M$, and $(q,\dot{q})$ are the induced coordinates on $TU\subset TM$. I would like to know if there exists a certain operation over vertical vector fields, let me denote it $X^\star$, such that
$$(X^v)^\star=X.$$

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the vertical lift produces vector fields which are constant on each fiber of $VTM$. As such, there is a bit of freedom in choosing a left inverse; here's one way of doing so.

Let $\xi:M\to TM$ be a vector field, and let $\Xi\subseteq TM$ be its image. We can restrict the vertical tangent bundle $VTM$ to a bundle over $\Xi$, given by $VTM|_{\Xi}$. The vertical lift then gives a bundle isomorphism $\operatorname{vl}_\xi:TM\to VTM|_{\Xi}$. A left inverse for the vertical lift of vector fields, $\varphi:\Gamma(VTM)\to\Gamma(TM)$ can then written as the restriction to $VTM|_{\Xi}$ followed by applying the identification between $VTM|_{\Xi}$ and $TM$. That is, for $p\in M$, we have
$$
(\varphi(X))(p)=\operatorname{vl}_{\xi}^{-1}(X(\xi(p))
$$
Since $\operatorname{vl}_\xi(X(p))=X^v(\xi(p))$ (since both are vertical lifts of $X(p)$) we have $\varphi(X^v)=X$.